# IDA Pro - How to edit structure's array size

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I have an executable file wrote in C++ and i'm trying to make some change on it

After use IDA Pro analyze this file, i wanna update initial variable in header file.
In detail, source code of header file declare and variable named _item_list like below

```
item _item_list[MAX_ITEM_IN_LIST];
```

The value of MAX_ITEM_IN_LIST is 100
And then in IDA Pro, i found it in Structures tab and it look like this

```
_item_list       item 100 dup(?)
```

How can i change intial size of _item_list from 100 to 1000 in IDA Pro?
And how to save the file after edit?

Comment: And then re-assemble a binary from modified asm source?  Or do you mean directly edit the binary, changing the address of all references to all other static data in the `.bss` that now have higher addresses because this one got bigger?  IDA might not support doing that.

Comment: @PeterCordes i mean just directly edit the binary to increase array size

Comment: Well like I said, that would require rewriting the address of all later `.bss` variables in every reference to them, because they'll be packed head to tail in memory.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, absolutely bad news :(